# Call a method of type parameter

Tags: c#, generics, type-parameter

Is there any way to do code such this:

```
class GenericClass<T>
{
    void functionA()
    {
        T.A();
    }
}
```

Or, how to call a function of type parameter (type is some my custom class).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call a method of a generic type object you have to instantiate it first.

```
public static void RunSnippet()
{
    var c = new GenericClass<SomeType>();
}

public class GenericClass<T> where T : SomeType, new()
{
    public GenericClass(){
        (new T()).functionA();
    }   
}

public class SomeType
{
    public void functionA()
    {
        //do something here
        Console.WriteLine("I wrote this");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to use public class GenericClass<T> where T : SomeType1, SomeType2, new()

Comment: No you can only specify one base class (you could create a SomeTypeBase, specify this as the type constraint and let SomeType1 and SomeType3 inherit from this SomeTypeBase class).

Answer (score 7):

Re:

> `T.A();`

You can't call static methods of the type-parameter, if that is what you mean. You would do better to refactor that as an instance method of `T`, perhaps with a generic constraint (`where T : SomeTypeOrInterface`, with `SomeTypeOrInterface` defining `A()`). Another alternative is `dynamic`, which allows duck-typing of *instance* methods (via signature).

If you mean that the `T` is only known at runtime (as a `Type`), then you would need:

```
typeof(GenericClass<>).MakeGenericType(type).GetMethod(...).Invoke(...);
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for [generic type constraints](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx):

```
class GenericClass<T> where T : MyBaseClass
{
    void functionA<T>(T something)
    {
        something.A();
    }
}
```

In terms of the code you posted - in order to call something on `T`, you will need to pass it as a parameter to `functionA`. The constraint you use will have to ensure that any `T` has an `A` method that can be used.

Comment: No, I have this error:


'T' is a 'type parameter', which is not valid in the given context

Comment: @shandu - answer updated. You need to supply the generic parameter as well.

Comment: Is it possible to use: class GenericClass<T> where T : MyBaseClass1, MyBaseClass2

Comment: @shandu - No, only one base class.

Comment: @Oded - Can MyBaseClass be interface, and then create MyBaseClass1 and MyBaseClass2 that will be inherent MyBaseClass

Comment: @shandu - You can simply use an interface as a generic type constraint. Read the link in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I understand from your code that you want to call a type parameter static method, and that's just impossible.

See here for more info : [Calling a static method on a generic type parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196661/calling-a-static-method-on-a-generic-type-parameter)