# Why I cannot await a Async method?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, async-await

**The code is below:**

```
public class XiciHttp
{
    public async Task<string> Login(string apiAddress)
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            return await client.GetStringAsync(apiAddress);
        }
    }
}
```

**The error happens in here:**

```
await client.GetStringAsync(apiAddress);
```

**The error message is:**

> Cannot convert expression type 'void' to async method return type
>   'string'

**The situation is:**
VS2012 Update 4;
Windows Phone Project (based on WP 7.1)
This class is in a PCL project
The project has refer lots of libs using NuGet (MS Async, HttpClient, Json.Net)


**The strange thing is:**
When I click "Build Solution", no error happens in the Error List window.
it said:
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========



**My Questiohn is:**
 1. Why
 2. How to solve it?

Comment: `using (client = new HttpClient())` This is not a particularly good pattern to use. `using (var client = new HttpClient())` would be better. That aside, is your problem with IntelliSense? Since your solution builds, and all.

Comment: Avoid var if you can, better `using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())`.

Comment: @ta.speot.is i've edit.. @_@

Comment: @pid, that's a personal style I'd say. I find it smarter and faster to write and the IDE tells me the rest.

Comment: Does this help you?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18562613/async-method-returning-taskt-with-generic-constraint-in-c-sharp

Comment: @pid Why? It's just a matter of opinion. In this case it is clear what the type is, so it's okay to use it.

Comment: are you sure that use system `HttpClient` and not custom class from lib?

Comment: It's a nuance, really. I'd advise to avoid var whenever possible because it shows you know what you are doing. It is not a matter of taste or style, it is a matter of [Clean Code](http://www.amazon.com/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882). This explains [why not to use var](http://www.brad-smith.info/blog/archives/336).

Comment: Usage of `var` isn't related to this question, please don't post irrelevant comments.

Comment: If your solution builds try cleaning the solution, closing VS and then opening it again.

Answer (score 0):

Restarting Visual Studio 2012 solved this error.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: I edited your answer to tone it down a little.

Comment: @Ascorbin ironically enough, this the the author of the question.

Comment: @Ascorbin The problem is with IntelliSense, there's no real error. See the question: *When I click "Build Solution", no error happens in the Error List window.* IntelliSense stuffed up. Restarting VS fixed it. What do you expect the answer to be?

Answer (score -1):

How do you call Login() ?
The following raises no errors.

```
private async void GetString()
{
    var str = await Login("http://www.google.com");
}

public async Task<string> Login(string apiAddress)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())        
        return await client.GetStringAsync(apiAddress);
}
```

Comment: Neither does the original code. It was an error with IntelliSense. *========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========*

Comment: How do you know? The question does not specify how the `Login()` function is being called. And whats with the downvote?

Comment: Because the question says that the IntelliSense error happens here `await client.GetStringAsync(apiAddress);`. Not `Login`...