# Pass dynamically type to generic template

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I am facing an issue with the reflection in C#. I need to construct a generic method that instantiate a class type dynamically with reflection. What I tried is the following.

```
Type myClass = Type.GetType(deviceBehavior.@class);
Type myInterfaceClass = myClass.GetInterface(deviceBehavior.@interface);

if (typeof (AnotherInterface).IsAssignableFrom(interfaceClass))
{
    CreateManager<interfaceClass>(serviceProvider, deviceCapability);
}
```

My CreateManager method is as following:

```
private void CreateManager<T>(ServiceProvider serviceProvider, DeviceCapability deviceCapability)
{
    T instanceToCreate = CreateClass<T>(serviceProvider, deviceCapability);
    //Code to instantiate my class
}
```

The problem is that I can't call

> CreateManager(serviceProvider, deviceCapability);

How can I pass an interface to my generic type? I searched and I couldn't find anything that I could understand clearly. i.e.

[Calling a static method on a generic type parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196661/calling-a-static-method-on-a-generic-type-parameter)

[Pass An Instantiated System.Type as a Type Parameter for a Generic Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/266115/pass-an-instantiated-system-type-as-a-type-parameter-for-a-generic-class)

Comment: Sorry but I could not understand what is the problem you face? What exactly you mean by "I Can't call" ?

Comment: I get the error "can not find symbol "interfaceClass"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2107845/generics-in-c-using-type-of-a-variable-as-parameter I think your question already exists but not 100% as I'm not that much into generics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets say `CreateManager<T>` is a method of type `Foo`:

```
public class Foo
{
    private void CreateManager<T>(ServiceProvider serviceProvider,
                                  DeviceCapability deviceCapability)
    {
    }
}
```

In order to dynamically invoke the generic method, you'll need to get the `MethodInfo` first, then call `MakeGenericMethod` with the actual type you want to pass (I choose `string` for the example)

```
var foo = new Foo();
var createManagerMethod = foo.GetType()
                             .GetMethod("CreateManager", 
                                         BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

var method = createManagerMethod.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(string));
method.Invoke(foo, new object[] { new ServiceProvider(), new DeviceCapability() });
```

Finally, call `Invoke` with the proper object instance and parameters.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I'm getting the same error "Can not find symbol" when I use my "Type object". I think the problem is that in this way the types are resolved at compilertime and with reflection types are resolved at runtime. Maybe is this?

Comment: Ok it worked perfectly! I changed the string typeof with a dinamyc instance of my type and it worked "MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { interfaceClass })"

Answer (score 0):

I don't see, why you need reflection for this. You could do it like shown below

```cs
public interface IYourInterface //Give it a good name
{
    void Instantiate(ServiceProvider serviceProvider, DeviceCapability deviceCapability);
}

public class YourClass : IYourInterface
{
    public YourClass() 
    {
        // do something if you want
    }

    public void Instantiate (ServiceProvider serviceProvider, DeviceCapability deviceCapability)
    {
       // what ever needs to be done here
    }
}

private void CreateManager<T>(ServiceProvider serviceProvider, DeviceCapability deviceCapability) 
    where T : IYourInterface, new()
{
    var instance = new T();
    instance.Instantiate(serviceProvider, deviceCapability);
}

/*
   Usage
*/

    CreateManager<YourClass>(serviceProvider, deviceCapability);
```

Comment: I need reflection because I read the classes dinamically from an option file and after that I must add them to the serviceProvider in runtime. i.e.

serviceProvider.Add<interfaceRead>(objectInstantiated);

Comment: Ok in that case, you cannot do it that way. ;o)

Comment: I finally did it. You can check the answer. Thank you for your response ;)

Comment: Thanks for keeping me up to date. Glad to hear that you could make it.