# How to define a static function with a generic return type meant to be overriden

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I am trying to do something so convoluted it's hurting my brain. So please, if you can think of a better way of doing it than what I'm asking for, I'm all ears!

Essentially I have a class, `ClientSession`, and this class accepts messages over tcp and exposes them through an `OnMessageReceived` event. I am trying to tell the `ClientSession` to parse the message before exposing it in the event using a `MessageParser` class, passed as a generic parameter. I want to use a static method to avoid instantiating objects for nothing. I also want anyone else to be able to create their own message parser that spits out whatever `Type` they want.

Essentially, I need to

- Guarantee to the `ClientSession` class that it can call `TryParse()` on the generic type I pass it during instantiation.
- implement `TryParse()` as a static method

Like this

```
public static abstract class MessageParser<TMessage>
{
    public static abstract TMessage TryParse(byte[] bytes);
}
```

Then someone else could define their own parser:

```
public static class ProtoParser : MessageParser<ProtoMessage>
{
    public static ProtoMessage TryParse(byte[] bytes)
    {
        do some stuff...
        return new ProtoMessage;
    }
}
```

and finally:

```
public class ClientSession<TParser>
{
    public void OnMessageReceived(Object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
    {
        return TParser.TryParse(e.bytes);
    }
{
```

I know that static and abstract together is impossible, but you get the idea.

I have a gut feeling that I'm just approaching this wrong. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can't. Make it an instance method and pass `ClientSession<TParser>` and instance of `TParser`. *Or*, pass `ClientSession` a method which it then invokes.

Comment: static methods can't be abstract. they are tied to the type defining them.

Comment: @Rob Each `ClientSession` could have a different `MessageParser` and I don't want to have to create a whole bunch of instances for each `ClientSession`.

Comment: @DanielA.White yes I know, I specifically said so at the bottom of my question. The example was to try to help you understand what I want.

Comment: @MatthewGoulart Then you can constrain the generic type as `where TParser : new()` and have `ClientSession` handle creating the `TParser` object.

Comment: "I want to use a static method to avoid instantiating objects for nothing" But it's not for nothing; the almost zero cost of instantiating an object gives you the benefit of *not having to use a static method that cannot be overridden*.  Staticness buys you nothing you actually want or need, so why is it a requirement?  Just abandon this entirely unnecessary requirement.

Comment: The lack of static inheritance is easily resolved by using static (eventually singleton) instance. Example - `EqualityComparer<T>.Default`, `Comparer<T>.Default` etc. In your case, something like second option in Rob's answer, but making `_parser` field `static readonly`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/196661/calling-a-static-method-on-a-generic-type-parameter) for why your current approach will not work and cannot work.

Some alternatives:

### Passing an instance of a parser

```
public abstract class MessageParser<TMessage>
{
    public abstract TMessage TryParse(byte[] bytes);
}

public class ProtoParser : MessageParser<ProtoMessage>
{
    public override ProtoMessage TryParse(byte[] bytes)
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public class ClientSession<TParser, TMessage> where TParser : MessageParser<TMessage>
{
    TParser _parser;
    public ClientSession(TParser parser)
    {
        _parser = parser;
    }

    public TMessage OnMessageReceived(Object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
    {
        return _parser.TryParse(e.bytes);
    }
}
```

And using it:

```
var cs = new ClientSession<ProtoParser, ProtoMessage>(new ProtoParser());
```

### Use instances of parsers created inside ClientSession

```
public abstract class MessageParser<TMessage>
{
    public abstract TMessage TryParse(byte[] bytes);
}

public class ProtoParser : MessageParser<ProtoMessage>
{
    public override ProtoMessage TryParse(byte[] bytes)
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public class ClientSession<TParser, TMessage> where TParser : MessageParser<TMessage>, new()
{
    TParser _parser = new TParser();

    public TMessage OnMessageReceived(Object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
    {
        return _parser.TryParse(e.bytes);
    }
}
```

And using it:

```
var cs = new ClientSession<ProtoParser, ProtoMessage>();
```

### Passing a method to `ClientSession`

```
public static class ProtoParser
{
    public static ProtoMessage TryParse(byte[] bytes)
    {
        return null;
    }
}

public class ClientSession<TMessage>
{
    Func<byte[], TMessage> _parser;
    public ClientSession(Func<byte[], TMessage> parser)
    {
        _parser = parser;
    }

    public TMessage OnMessageReceived(Object sender, MessageEventArgs e)
    {
        return _parser(e.bytes);
    }
}
```

And then using it:

```
var cs = new ClientSession<ProtoMessage>(ProtoParser.TryParse);
```

Comment: Thanks rob I'll look over these and get back asap!