# C# Generic Return Type of Calling Object Type

Tags: c#, methods, reflection, extension-methods

I am making a class to abstract some functionality that I will be using in multiple other classes in my project. This class converts objects to and from JSON and also deep copies objects.

```
public abstract class Serializable
{
    public T Copy<T>()
    {
        return Deserialize<T>(Serialize());
    }

    public string Serialize()
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
    }

    public static T Deserialize<T>(string json)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
    }
}
```

This code works as intended; however, I would like to simplify the syntax of the `Copy` and `Desirialize` functions. Currently, a call looks like this `copy = descendantClassInstance.Copy<descendantClass>()` which is wordy and also leaves room for error in that `copy = otherdescendantClassInstance.Copy<descendantClass>()` would compile but yield an error at runtime. I would prefer the return type be automatically inferred based on the type of the calling object, like `copy = descendantClassInstance.Copy()`, without overriding the `Copy` or `Desirialize` method in each descendant class.

How can I do this?

**Edit:**

Extensions seem to be a possible avenue for implementing `Copy` as desired. However, I also want similar functionality for `Deserialize`, which is static. From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/196977/12297767), it doesn't seem doable with extensions.

An acceptable answer will handle both of these case.

Comment: here's an option for a deep copy - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129389/how-do-you-do-a-deep-copy-of-an-object-in-net

Comment: `public abstract class Serializable<T>`.

Comment: @DanielA.White I am referencing that question in constructing my class already. However, it is not clear to me how they make the leap to `objectBeingCloned.Clone();` In fact, making `Clone` a static method seems to be a step in the wrong direction for what I want. After all, I want to call it from an instance of the object.

Comment: @mjwills Explanation please?

Comment: @Groger The answer below fleshes out the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use

```
public abstract class Serializable<T>
{
    public T Copy()
    {
        return Deserialize(Serialize());
    }

    public string Serialize()
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
    }

    public static T Deserialize(string json)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(json);
    }
}
```

And to implement it like this:

```
public class Test : Serializable<Test>
{
}
```

However, note that this will require you to continue the chain if you want further descendants of your class to have the most derived type:

```
public class Base<T> : Serializable<T> where T : Base<T>
{
}

public class Derived : Base<Derived>
{
}
```

This may or may not be acceptable depending on your use case.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve it via extension method:

```
public static class SerializableExtension
{
   public static T Copy<T>(this T instance) where T: Serializable
   {
      return Serializable.Deserialize<T>(instance.Serialize());
   }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
public class A: Serializable
{
}

public class B
{
    public void SomeMethod(A item)
    {
       var newItem = item.Copy();
    }
}
```

Comment: What does a method call look like? `SerializableExtension.Copy(objectBeingCloned)`? That's even further from my desired solution.

Comment: Also, `public static T Copy<T>(this T instance)`

Comment: No, extension method will work just as you want: `objectToClone.Copy()`. Consider `this T instance`

Comment: So does `objectToClone` need to be descendant of `SerializableExtension` type? I can't derive a non-static class from a static class.

Comment: No. It shouldn't. Read about extension methods, for example, here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods. Idea is that it's like syntactic sugar, you write in your code `objectToClone.Copy()` and compiler treats it as `SerializableExtension.Copy(objectBeingCloned)`. The only drawback - SerializableExtension should be in `using` list. BTW, that's the way `Enumerable` functions like `Where`, `Select` and others work.

Comment: So what do I need to get `Serializable` to recognize the extension? Your current code throws a compiler error, and adding `<T>` as I suggested doesn't register as an extension like you describe.

Comment: You're write - I forgot `<T>`. Corrected answer and added sample usage.

Comment: And, BTW, remove `Copy` from `Serializable` class.

Comment: Sorry to rescind your solution. What about the `Desirialize` case? That should be a static method of the derived classes (`derivedClassInstance = DerivedClass.Deserialize(json)`). Extensions don't seem to work the same with static methods.

Comment: Well, as for `Deserialize` I don't know any very good option - extension methods can only be applied to instances. You can actually make `public static T Deserialize<T>(this string json)` and call it like: `json.Deserialize<DerivedClass>`, but I'm not sure this will satisfy you.